# Troubleshooting problem cause

Tags: troubleshooting

So I did head gasket replacement on my Dodge and now I've had spark advance readings initially say 5, now it's - 64. Is this because the timing wasn't on? This is a interference engine, so are my valves and or pistons now messed up perhaps. Dnt hear pinging or knocking. So was my timing belt possibly 180 degrees turned around? The belt was installed after water pump job B4 blowing head gasket, and was driving less than 500 miles with the new belt, but if it was installed the reverse way, would that do it?? I've had p1005 code, then p0660, which I replaced and got p1005, so I replaced that one and it went back to 0660. So throttle bodies bad? PCM? Tps? Any advice appreciated. Car is running rough with check engine lite for two previously mentioned codes. Help!?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/model/engine of your Dodge?